# Redirect to action and passing reference type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a `Filter` type:

```
public class Filter 
{
   public int FilterId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<int> ModuleIds { get; set; }
}
```

I need to redirect to action and pass instanse of this type:

```
public ActionResult Navigate 
{
   var filter = new Filter()
   {
      FilterId = 5,
      ModuleIds = new List<int>() { 6 };
   }

   return RedirectToAction("list", "user", filter);
}
```

Here is the target action :

```
public ActionResult List(Filter filter) 
{
  var filterId = filter.FilterId; // = 5
  // but filter.ModuleIds.Count = 0 
}
```

In a result I got empty `filter.ModuleIds`. So, there is a issue only with reference type.

How can I pass `filter` with all reference properties without using `TempData`?

Also I tried to use but no results

```
return RedirectToAction("list", "user", new RouteValueDictionary(filter);
```

and

```
return RedirectToAction"list", "user", new { filter = filter} );
```

Comment: You can't pass reference types. A workaround would be saving the value in Session/TempData or serializing the `filter` object to json which would make it a value type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass reference types. The reason is that `RedirectToAction` doesn't serialize the data, it simply iterates over the properties in the route values object constructing a query string with the keys being the property names and the values the string representation of the property values. If you want to have the `Url` change, then using `TempData` is probably the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm going to use Session if there is no ways to pass my object